# How to troubleshoot Integrated Authentication problems for asp.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication

How to troubleshoot Integrated Authentication problems for asp.net core 2.1

Page requests to my asp.net core 2.1.x application published to IIS using Visual Studio 2017 publish, return HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized.
The IIS Server application is configured to use only Integrated Authentication.
[IIS Manager Window Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHPGZ.png)

In the snippet, the Default Web Site/OrderTrackingService is the application created and configured by Visual Studio debugging. The Dev.Portal/ordertracking is the same application published via a publish profile from visual studio.

As far as I can tell, the web app configuration in IIS is identical.
When I run the application under the debugger, using IIS or IIS Express the incoming requests have an authorization header

```
No Proxy-Authorization Header is present.
Authorization Header (Negotiate) appears to contain a Kerberos ticket:

    60 81 84 06 06 2B 06 01 05 05 02 A0 7A 30 78 A0  `..+..... z0x 
    30 30 2E 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02 0A 06  00...+....7....
    09 2A 86 48 82 F7 12 01 02 02 06 09 2A 86 48 86  .*H÷......*H
    F7 12 01 02 02 06 0A 2B 06 01 04 01 82 37 02 02  ÷......+....7..
```

…

When I run the application from IIS Directly ( as configured by publish and the IIS settings ) the incoming requests do not have an authorization header

```
No Authorization Header is present.
```

Can anybody tell me how I can determine why the headers are present in one case and missing in the other case?

UPDATE: 
I have some additional information that may help with tracking down the issue. When requests to the web application set up by visual studio debugging are made to IIS there is series of HTTP request/responses where the auth header is provided and the user identity is established.

**- REQUEST/RESPONSE**

```
GET http://.../ordertrackingservice HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .AspNet.Consent=yes

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 16:32:36 GMT
Content-Length: 6138
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

**
 **- REQUEST/RESPONSE**
**

```
GET http://.../ordertrackingservice HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

> Authorization: Negotiate YIGEBgYrB....

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .AspNet.Consent=yes

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

> WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYIBUTCCAU2gAwoBAaEMBgorBgE...

```
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 16:32:36 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

**
 **- REQUEST/RESPONSE**
**

```
GET http://.../ordertrackingservice HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Negotiate oXcwdaADCgEBoloEWE5UTE1TU1...
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .AspNet.Consent=yes

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Kestrel
Persistent-Auth: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAAAVmumr4Z49ZwAAAAA=
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 16:32:36 GMT
Content-Length: 6884
```

When requests are made to the website created by the visual studio publish tool this negotiation does not happen. There is a single request/reponse

```
GET http://...:8081/ordertracking HTTP/1.1
Host: ...:8081
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .AspNet.Consent=yes

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 02 Oct 2018 17:00:10 GMT
Content-Length: 5955
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

The only thing that is different about the configuration as far as I can tell is that the published website has bindings to port 8081. The exact same code is running in both cases so this must be some kind of configuration issue.

Given:
In the working case the initial response is coming from IIS, the second response is coming from Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0, and the third response is coming from Kestrel.

Followup Questions:
Is the middle server part of the ASP.Net core module? 
Is it possible that this is missing some kind of config setup that prevents it from receiving the handoff? (like its only listening on port 80 or something)

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I was running into was caused by a group policy that was blocking clients from NTLM authentication for hosts, not in the group policy whitelist. I am not sure why Kerberos authentication was not used, but adding the host to the whitelist allowed the authentication negotiation to proceed.